# Gnome 3.8 weather app permissions issue

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I installed the weather app and added a city.  However, the weather info never displayed. 
I was abe to see the following error information.

```
Gio.IOErrorEnum: Error opening file '/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/weather-extension@xeked.com/weather-prefs.log': Permission denied

Stack trace:
  WeatherPrefsWidglet<.status@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/weather-extension@xeked.com/prefs.js:90
  wrapper@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:213
  WeatherPrefsWidget<.initWindow@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/weather-extension@xeked.com/prefs.js:104
  wrapper@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:213
  WeatherPrefsWidget<._init@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/weather-extension@xeked.com/prefs.js:71
  wrapper@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:213
  buildPrefsWidget@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/weather-extension@xeked.com/prefs.js:653
  Application<._selectExtension@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/extensionPrefs/main.js:100
  wrapper@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:213
  Application<._extensionSelected@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/extensionPrefs/main.js:119
  wrapper@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:213
  Application<._selectExtension@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/extensionPrefs/main.js:110
  wrapper@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:213
  Application<._extensionsLoaded@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/extensionPrefs/main.js:219
  wrapper@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:213
  _emit@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/signals.js:124
  ExtensionFinder<._extensionsLoaded@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/extensionUtils.js:178
  wrapper@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:213
  done@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/fileUtils.js:33
  @/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/fileUtils.js:51
  onNextFileComplete@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/fileUtils.js:21
  main@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/extensionPrefs/main.js:276
  @<command line>:1
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and the below answer does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Open Nautilus (that's the proper name for "Files" btw) - or any file manager - as root: `gksudo nautilus` in the terminal (replacing nautilus with a different FM if you wish). Then, navigate to /usr/share and right-click gnome-shell, go to permissions, and make sure you have permissions to edit it. Try that